# Contributions of Mary Cartwright to the theory of entire functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, ho.history-overview

I have seen on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Cartwright) for the mathematician Mary Cartwright that she achieved many new results in the field of entire functions and the zeroes of entire functions and that many of these were included in her 1956 book on the subject.

I do not have access to this book, and was wondering if anyone could tell me the specific main results which Cartwright contributed in this area (I already know of Cartwright's theorem from the Wikipedia page).

Edit: Changed 'integral' to 'entire'

Comment: I think it took me all of a minute to think that probably by "integral functions" you probably meant what I was taught to call "entire functions". I'd heard of that usage before, but I don't know that I've ever seen it before.

Comment: Yes, I believe the more modern term is now to call these functions 'entire'.

Comment: you may find this overview informative: https://www.ams.org/notices/199902/mem-cartwright.pdf

Comment: Ah...thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don’t you have access to the book?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mary Cartwright proved many important theorems in the theory of entire functions (too many to list them here). For a survey of her contributions I recommend  her obituary:

[Zbl 1032.01034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1032.01034)
Hayman, W. K.
Mary Lucy Cartwright (1900–1998),
Bull. London Math. Soc. 34 (2002), no. 1, 91–107.

written by Hayman, who also made many important contributions to entire functions.

Nowadays she is more famous for her contribution to non-linear dynamics (partially joint with Littlewood) but these papers were VERY much ahead of their time, and were not sufficiently appreciated until the late 1980s. Before that she was more famous for her contribution to the theory entire functions. For example, the class of entire functions of exponential type with
the property
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\log|f(x)|}{1+x^2}dx<\infty,$$
which plays a fundamental role in harmonic analysis, is called the *Cartwright class*. (The principal theorem about zero distribution of functions of this class is called Levinson's theorem, but it was proved independently by Levinson [and Cartwright](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A56.0973.02)). Many of her results on entire functions were improved since then or absorbed into more general theories, but her [book on entire functions](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0075.05901) remains one of her most cited works.

Comment: Is there something missing from your statement? You have an integral but nothing about it. Is there supposed to be a bound on that integral or a statement about an integrality condition?

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Thanks. I corrected.